# Excel conditional formatting for the entire row with more than one formula

Tags: excel, formula, rule, conditional-formatting

After 3 hours of searching I still didn't find an answer, here is what I am trying to do:

I am trying to fill with green any row that has WBS in it and with Red any row that has ACT in it and Blue any row that has EPR in it. It works for the first formula then when I try to add the second one every thing get messed up.

Comment: Please update your question and include the formula(s) you've used and how you've applied them to your worksheet

Comment: Please be more specific when you say "every thing get messed up". Can you give us a step-by-step of what you did?

Answer (score 0):

what i have understood is that you need to search a keyword in a row and if its found in any cell of that row then color it.

May be we can do it with conditional formatting but i have another idea. We can create a simple search function in Excel VBA. Something like this:

=search_row(A1:F1,"EPR")

The function will return 1 if EPR is found in any cell of specified row. Now if you create two different columns at the end of data columns, name first with WPS and second with EPR and write this function in it. Like

G1 =search_row(A1:F1,"WPS")

H1 =search_row(A1:F1,"EPR")

Drag it to end. Now sort the columns. First for WPS from higher to lower. Then color all rows having 1 in a single select. Similarly do the same with EPR (H1) column.

To use this function you can download the macro file from the following URL:

http://asimishaq.com/myfiles/SearchHighlight.xlsm

Now to run it first of all enable macros, and then re-open your data file and then open this macro file. As long as this macro file is opened you can use this function. Following is the VBA code if you want to create the macro yourself:

```
Function search_row(sRow As Range, Keyword As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Found As Integer

    For i = 1 To sRow.Columns.Count
        If InStr(1, LCase(sRow.Cells(1, i)), LCase(Keyword)) > 0 Then
          search_row = 1
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a go at making a function similar to asim-ishaq to determine if your search term exists in the row for fun :) then tried to apply it to highlighting rows, turns out I dont know how to use conditional formatting very well! Figured it out in the end, hopefully I've explained it well enough.

With this you will have to have (one) extra column at the end of your data to contain the result.

It might be possible to not require the extra column by putting the function inside the conditional formatting, however I couldn't get it to work (didn't try very hard). This isn't a great loss as it's much simpler to edit the formula if its on the workbook, instead of having to go through each conditional rule to edit it, should you need to edit it in the future.

To get the formatting to work you will need to create a number of rules (one per keyword)

[image: example formatting for 3 keywords]

You want to create a rule of the type shown below, in the formula box you need something along the lines of: `=INDIRECT("D" & ROW())=0` where `D` is the column containing the result of the function below and `0` is the index of the keyword you're highlighting.

In my example, the formula in the `D` Column is: `=SearchRow(An:Cn,"ABS","KBS","JBS")` (where n is the row the formula is on)

Set the formatting as desired then press OK, when you return to the rule manager you will need to update the `Applies to` value, which should be a range that covers all the data you want to highlight. In my example it was `$A$1:$C$3`

[image: type of rule to add]

My function below takes 2+ Arguments, The first is the range to search. The second (and any subsequent ones) are search terms.

The function will return a number. -1 for no matches and 0+ for the found search term. The number depends on the position in the arguments.

```
A1 = "ABS"
B1 = "SBA"

A2 = "SBA"
B2 = "ABS"

A3 = ""
B3 = ""

C1 = "=SearchRow(A1:B1, "ABS", "SBA")"
C2 = "=SearchRow(A2:B2, "ABS", "SBA")"
C3 = "=SearchRow(A3:B3, "ABS", "SBA")"

C1 > 0
C2 > 1
C3 > -1
```

The function will always return the first result, searching left to right comparing each cell to the Keywords in order. Using my example, if a cell contained "SBA ABS" the result would be 0 (for ABS). I guess your cells will probably only contain one keyword though so this shouldn't be a problem?

```
Public Function SearchRow(ByVal Row As Range, ParamArray Keyword() As Variant) As Integer
Dim Column As Integer
Dim Value As String
Dim Index As Integer
Dim Result As Integer
For Column = 1 To Row.Columns.Count
    Value = LCase(Row.Cells(1, Column))
    Result = -1
    For Index = LBound(Keyword) To UBound(Keyword)
        If InStr(1, Value, LCase(Keyword(Index))) > 0 Then
            Result = Index
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Index
    If Result > -1 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next Column
SearchRow = Result
End Function
```